# how to dual boot Redhat and ubuntu on using different partitions

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, redhat-enterprise-linux

I want to dual boot my laptop using RedHat and Ubuntu in different partitions. 
My hardisk contains the following partitions:

```
/boot ==> redhat boot partition 300MB
/SWAP ===> 8GB
/ ===> UBUNTU ROOT
/ ===> RedHat Root.
/Sharing ==> to be shared between the two linux os.
```

I installed RedHat first without the grub option, followed by Ubuntu with 
the grub installed in "/dev/sda" (MBR).
My problem is that I have not been able to boot the RedHat, 
I have tried all tools available to configure the grub but I have failed.
I updated legacy grub to Grub2 in Ubuntu.

below is the grub entry for ubuntu===>

```
#BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-38-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 0275f7b6-ff36-42a2-9d89-03195b9de12a
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-38-generic root=UUID=0275f7b6-ff36-42a2-9d89-03195b9de12a ro   quiet splash
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-38-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-38-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 0275f7b6-ff36-42a2-9d89-03195b9de12a
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-38-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-38-generic root=UUID=0275f7b6-ff36-42a2-9d89-03195b9de12a ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-38-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 0275f7b6-ff36-42a2-9d89-03195b9de12a
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 0275f7b6-ff36-42a2-9d89-03195b9de12a
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
#RedHat Menu by pato
menuentry 'RedHat Enterprise 5.4' {
    set root='(hd0,4)'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-164.el5 root=/dev/sda4
    initrd  /boot/initrd-2.6.18-164.el5.img
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
=====================end of ubuntu Grub.=================
```

Please help by a step by step guide to install the two linux operating systems and configure grub for dualboot.

Comment: [This](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-grub-configfile.html) guide on how to add RHE to the grub menu entries list might help you. Remember to use your kernel version and volume/partition instead -- issue `fdisk -l` to see your partitions and `uname -r` to see your kernel version.

Comment: #RedHat Menu To Insert 
menuentry 'RedHat Enterprise 5.4' {
 root='(hd0,1)' # partition that Holds Grub.
 linux /vmlinuz-2.6.18-164.el5 root=/dev/sda3 #load the linux kernel
 initrd /initrd-2.6.18-164.el5.img
 #boot
} The above menu results to errors: file not found and need to load kernel first